# this в addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Как правильно через addEventListener передать this, в функцию deleteFile?

```
function deleteFile (e)
    {
        console.log(e.dataset.file);
    }

    btnsDeleteFile = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteFile');
    for (var i = 0; i < btnsDeleteFile.length; i++) {
        btnsDeleteFile[i].addEventListener('click', deleteFile);
    }
```

Comment: А какой `this` вы хотите передать? В смысле, на что он должен ссылаться?

Comment: у функции deleteFile нужно получить элемент на который был клик, то есть this это элемент

Comment: Причем тут `this`, когда дело в `event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов.

Замыкание:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.deleteFile')].forEach(el => 
    el.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(el))
);
```

```html
<div class='deleteFile'>1</div>
<div class='deleteFile'>2</div>
<div class='deleteFile'>3</div>
```

This, как вы просили:

```js
function deleteFile (e) {
    console.log(this);
}
    
[...document.querySelectorAll('.deleteFile')].forEach(el => 
   el.addEventListener('click', deleteFile));
```

```html
<div class='deleteFile'>1</div>
<div class='deleteFile'>2</div>
<div class='deleteFile'>3</div>
```

event.target

```js
function deleteFile (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
    
[...document.querySelectorAll('.deleteFile')].forEach(el => 
   el.onclick = deleteFile);
```

```html
<div class='deleteFile'>1</div>
<div class='deleteFile'>2</div>
<div class='deleteFile'>3</div>
```